# How to fix Unirest bad request response (Error 400)

Tags: java, httpresponse, unirest

I have this unirest request that works perfectly on my local. However, whenever I use the same request on our UAT server, it returns an `Error 400` which is equivalent to a bad request.

I learned that this means that there may be something wrong with the syntax of the request or maybe anything close to that. However my request works when I use it from my local computer so I guess that means my code works fine.

As a result, I'm running out of ideas which parts I should check to make this work. Below are my codes which I labeled to indicate which one was used from my local and which was used from the UAT server:

**From Local:**

```
public static String getConsumerBill(String accNum) {
    //getToken() is a method that returns a Token object that I made
    Token accessToken = getToken();

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = Unirest.post("http://api.nuvelco.com/v1/bill/inquiry")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .header("authorization", "Bearer " + response.getAccess_token())
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .body("{\"accountNo\":\"" + accNum + "\"}")
                .asString();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return httpResponse.getBody();
}
```

**From UAT Server**

```
public static String getConsumerBill (String accNum) {
    Token accessToken = getToken();

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = null;
    try {
        /*
            urlInquiry is a global variable that gets its value from a database
            the value it gets is the same as the url from above
        */
        httpResponse = Unirest.post(urlInquiry)
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .header("authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccess_token())
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .body("{\"accountNo\":\"" + accNum + "\"}")
                .asString();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return httpResponse.getBody();
}
```

As you can probably tell, the only difference I made was with the URL. Its hardcoded in my local while the one from the UAT server gets it from a database. Other than that I'm not sure why the UAT version is returning a `Bad Request` response.

The request from my local returns the response below with the error code 404, which is normal and it means it works:

```
{"message":"Invalid account no.","code":1}
```

The one from the UAT server returns this, with error code 400:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

In addition to that, I can't even print that body but I can print out the status code. I wanted to ask our client about this but I kept thinking that the request works fine on my local so that means their web service is working fine.

Please do tell me if there any are other information I need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer with this information, but some tips:

400 Bad Request indicates invalid/malformed request which did not comply with the server side API rules.
With the information provided, please request for server side logs to see what went wrong.

Please be sure that same server/URL is getting hit on both scenarios, by verifying server logs.
It is possible that the second scenario hit a different server - a different API version where possibly the request model was changed ?

Use Chrome Advanced REST Client or a tool like SoapUI to debug if required.